# Plausibility of my alien race

Tags: internal-consistency, technology, aliens, wormholes, zero-point-energy

I came up with an alien race for a video game I'm developing, and I wanted to know if they would be scientifically plausible. They call themselves (rough translation) the Valke. They are humanoids with reptilian skin, and their average height and weight are 6' and 130 kg respectively. Their homeworld is an ice world called Odin and they have black scales to absorb all the light they can. They may have reptilian skin, but they are cold-blooded. Rather than the stereotypical crocodilian heads, they have downward-wedge-shaped heads, with a protuberance at the top back. I wanted to know; Are the Valke plausible?

Comment: "They are humanoids with reptilian skin, and their average height and weight are 6' and 130 kg respectively." Is this all that you want checked for plausibility of your race?

Comment: If you're asking about their science/tech - that's the sort of thing you should ask in its own thread.

Comment: Yeah, that's two questions. And spoiler alert: none of your tech is plausible given real-world physics, and just sounds like technobabble. That shouldn't stop you including it in your game, but you should have a think about how much value "plausibility" will add; there's nothing wrong with soft scifi, and hard scifi is hard work and not necessarily rewarding.

Comment: The edit doesn't help much, as the two questions are entangled. Please focus on one question at a time.

Comment: "Unusually for reptiles, they are cold-blooded" As far as I know, all reptiles are cold-blooded. It's part of the definition..

Answer (score 1):

Given that you’ve decided to use a new element, you would need to decide on boundaries for what said element is used for, and how it is harnessed. It may be useful to look into nuclear energy, as that is considered an unstable energy source, but it has been harnessed for use in multiple fields.
So, as long as you ensure scientific boundaries to singularium, your concept seems plausible.

Answer (score 1):

### "Who knows?" and "Who knows?"

> They are humanoids with reptilian skin, and their average height and weight are 6' and 130 kg respectively.

That's not a lot of information to go on. About all I can say without making assumptions is that "130 kg" is perhaps a bit hefty, but not unrealistic.

Realism aside, you're basically describing the [Gorn](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Gorn); hopefully you have some other distinguishing features to make sure Star Trek fans don't start screaming "cOpYrIgHt InFrInGeMeNt!!!!"

> They have Casimir power tech, and while developing it, they discovered that an element called singularium is buried at the core of a black hole, and quantum-entangled singularium creates stable wormholes.

- Casimir Effect-powered generators: They're reasonably plausible.
- Singularium: Sure, I guess. You might as well call it "Handwavium;" it's a fictional material that you use to conveniently [handwave](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HandWave) cool stuff. As such, I can't pass judgement on its realism.

Comment: *"Realism aside, you're basically describing the Gorn"* [or the visitors in V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_(1983_miniseries)), or any one of many many (many?) other sci fi aliens for that matter, humanoid lizard aliens, it's a pretty ubiquitous sci fi trope.